# For every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, find the rank and nullity of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

For every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, find the rank and nullity of the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
\lambda  & 2 & 3 &1 \\ 
1 & 4 & 1 & 1\\ 
5 & 1 & 1 &1 \\ 
7 & \lambda & 3 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 3 &1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}

I tried eliminating to REF form by hand, but it just gets messy and I'm not sure what to make of the matrix I get. Should I be trying to look for special cases of lambda from REF form or is there a better way of finding the rank and nullity

Comment: Well, the upper right $3 \times 3$ minor is invertible, so there aren't too many options for the rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try subtracting the first row from the other rows.